# Redirect from all http to https in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

To be able to redirect all http to https I´ve used following .htaccess:

```
Options All -Indexes DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Regarding the documentation I´ve read it should be working.

But the problem is that I receive error 310: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to not base it on a server port but just check whether its not HTTPS, also using specific server names can help it be a bit easier when deploying!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted to support at hosting company as well and got an answer finally which worked.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

The addition of RewriteBase / seems to do the trick.